# Importing Multiple Top Levels XML into Excel

Tags: excel, xml, import

I am trying to import the following which are all top level elements in Excel and get this error:

Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.Line 2, Position 2

Here is a sample with names changed to protect the info:

```
enter code here
<restrictions>
  <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
  <description>Enable Test</description>
  <key>Test_agent_enabled</key>
  <restrictionType>bool</restrictionType>
  <title>Enable Test</title>
  <configUri>content://com.test.test/boolean/preferences/test_agent_enabled</configUri>
</restrictions>
<restrictions>
  <defaultValue></defaultValue>
  <description>Endpoint URL</description>
  <key>cloud_endpoint</key>
  <restrictionType>string</restrictionType>
  <title>Endpoint URL</title>
  <configUri>content://com.test.test/string/preferences/cloud_endpoint</configUri>
</restrictions>
enter code here
```

I have many of these blocks that I need to put into Excel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your XML is malformed. As the error message says, only one top level element is allowed, and your XML contains two top level elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new top level tag to fix it:

```
<top>
<restrictions>
<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
<description>Enable Test</description>
<key>Test_agent_enabled</key>
<restrictionType>bool</restrictionType>
<title>Enable Test</title>
<configUri>content://com.test.test/boolean/preferences/test_agent_enabled</configUri>
</restrictions>
<restrictions>
<defaultValue></defaultValue>
<description>Endpoint URL</description>
<key>cloud_endpoint</key>
<restrictionType>string</restrictionType>
<title>Endpoint URL</title>
<configUri>content://com.test.test/string/preferences/cloud_endpoint</configUri>
</restrictions>
</top>
```